# How to compare two numbers with tolerance?

Tags: python

I have been struggling with this part of my code. I created a function with three parameters, two of which are the numbers being compared and the third is the allowed tolerance. I can compare the two numbers if the tolerance is zero but how would I be able to test them with a tolerance not equal to zero?

For example:

```
function_name((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), 0)) #Should return True
function_name((1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 3), 0)) #Should return False
function_name((1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 3), 1)) #Should return True
```

For tolerance 0:

```
    if tolerance == 0:
        if t1 == t2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `t1-t2 <= tolerance`? Assuming t1 and t2 are both numbers, I think this would solve your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how do you calculate the tolerance?

Comment: Do you want to compare the difference between each element to the tolerance, or should the difference between all elements be less then your tolerance? So, should `foo((1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 4), 1)` return `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tolerance between the two whole tuples to be equal or less then the tolerance, this function should suffice:

```
import numpy as np

def bar(t1, t2, tolerance):
    off = abs((np.array(t1)-np.array(t2))).sum()
    return True if off <= tolerance else False
```

If you mean to check if the difference between each element in the two tuples is less then the tolerance, this works:

```
def bar(t1, t2, tolerance):
    for e1, e2 in zip(t1, t2):
        if (abs(e1-e2) > tolerance): return False
    return True
```